# Edit: This question no longer applies, as I asked out of my own beginner oversight. Please do not trouble yourself to answer

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def is_palindrome(name):
    if "".join(reversed(name.lower())) == name.lower():
       
        return "Congratulations, {0} is a palindrome!".format(name)
    else:
        return f"Sorry! {name} is not a palindrome."
    
    
print(is_palindrome("roger"))
```

I expected the function to convert all names so that they would be in lower-case format first, before being iterated the opposite way. (Through the reversed function). At first, for my else statement, I just wrote "pass" under it. When I used names like "Hannah", I kept getting "None".

Comment: `== name.lower()` fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def is_palindrome(name):
    name = name.lower()  # convert the name to lower-case
    reversed_name = "".join(reversed(name))  # reverse the name
    if reversed_name == name:
        return f"Congratulations, {name} is a palindrome!"
    else:
        return f"Sorry! {name} is not a palindrome."
```